Cannot extract the penultimate layer output of a vision transformer with a Pytorch
I have the following model that I tuned with my own dataset trained with DataParallel:
model = timm.create_model('vit_base_patch16_224', pretrained=False)
model.head = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(768, 512),nn.ReLU(),nn.BatchNorm1d(512),nn.Dropout(p=0.2),nn.Linear(512, 141))
checkpoint = torch.load('vit_b_16v3.pth')
checkpoint = {k.partition('module.')[2]: v for k, v in checkpoint.items()}
# Load parameters
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint)

However, I have no idea on how to get the penultimate layer output of such a vision transformer. I tried This tutorial but it is not working. I only want to input an image and have a 512-D vector describing it. With Tensorflow it is a piece of cake to do it but in Pytorch I am struggling.
My last layers are as follows:
(norm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-06, elementwise_affine=True)
  (fc_norm): Identity()
  (head_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
  (head): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): BatchNorm1d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (3): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=False)
    (4): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=141, bias=True)
  )
)


As explained in the timm documentation, you can get the final hidden state of the model with the forward_features method.
model = timm.create_model(...)
x = ...
features = model.forward_features(x)


I will test it and give you feedback soon. Thank you!
